# MySQL 5.0 table with multiple keys and no primary key

Tags: mysql, key, myisam

I am updating a wordpress site. The create statement is:

```
  CREATE TABLE `wp_plugins_submits` (
  `submit_time` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL,
  `form_name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `field_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` longblob,
  KEY `submit_time_idx` (`submit_time`),
  KEY `form_name_idx` (`form_name`),
  KEY `field_name_idx` (`field_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This gives a 'no primary key error' on MySQL 5.6 (seems right to me). The create statement comes out of a database dump so I assume this works on 5.0 but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really having a table, which puts the question beyond the scope of the tagged items.

Comment: The query looks right to me as well. It was executed with no errors on MySQL 5.7.23 & MariaDB 10.1.14. Are you sure that this query is causing the error you mentioned?

Comment: I've created many tables with no primary key, MySQL doesn't impose that as a requirement.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Maybe it's coming from WordPress, not MySQL.

Comment: Is it claiming that is a fatal error, or merely a warning?

Comment: This is a wordpress error coming out of updating the submit plugin. I [thought] I entered the command as show. After reading your answers I did a cut & paste. The above works using the cli on MySQL 5.3 and 5.6. So a bug in the plugin compounded by my typing skills.